# How to prevent saving duplicate paragraphs in JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. I am badly stuck to figure out how to prevent saving duplicate data into an array. Basically,when i click on any two of paragraph elements then the text contain in paragraph saved into an array called test.But, I want, when I click any paragraph twice then text must not be saved into an array.I want to prevent any duplicate entry.

```js
var test = [];

[...document.querySelectorAll(".container")].forEach(div => div.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "P") {
    test.push(e.target.textContent);
  }
  console.log(test);
}));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <b>Group:N</b>Code:1234<br/>
    <b> Session Type:CS<br/>
    <b> Location:Main Hall<br/>
    <b>Time:14:00<br/>
    <b>Day:Tuesday<br/>
    <b>Duration:1hour<br/>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p> 
    <b>Group:M</b>Code:98743<br/>
    <b> Session Type:NP<br/>
    <b> Location:Main Hall2<br/>
    <b>Time:11:00<br/>
    <b>Day:Monday<br/>
    <b>Duration:1hour<br/>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I checked this but before but it did not work in my case.Thanks

Comment: You can use Array.includes() to check if an element is in the array

Comment: I recognise that code. If you had posted more HTML and asked a more detailed question in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731035/how-to-store-each-paragraph-into-an-javascript-array-when-onclick-event-occurs) I could have given a better answer

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for ur reply, basically I jusy want to make it simple.

Comment: @Loxx if IE11 is not needed otherwise you need babel

Comment: @David I updated my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59731159/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan Many thanks.Yes Its perfectly working now. My bad, I must explain it yesterday..

Comment: I have just posted a question. Can you please help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752075/how-to-validate-data-into-paragraphs-text-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if the array already contains the item or not. If it doesnt then `push` or else ignore. Use `Array.prototype.includes` for this.

```js
var test = [];
[...document.querySelectorAll(".container")].forEach(div => div.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "P") {
    var text = e.target.textContent;
    if (!test.includes(text)) // This is the code to stop repeating elements.
      test.push(text);
  }
  console.log(test);
}));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This code does not work proper with the current HTML. Anyway it's a dupe

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It works but when I want to display error  message if I click twice a same p, in console using else but this is not working...

Comment: @David I think this wasnt the original scope of what has been asked. If this solves the problem you may close the question by marking the answer correct and ask another question. This keep SO concise!

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a paragraph add `data-checked` next time you click on it you can check `e.target.dataset.checked` if it's true don't add it.

```js
var test = [];

[...document.querySelectorAll(".container")].forEach(div => div.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "P" && !e.targed.dataset.checked) {

    test.push(e.target.textContent);
    e.target.dataset.checked = true;
  }
  console.log(test); 
}));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <b>Group:N</b>Code:1234<br/>
    <b> Session Type:CS<br/>
    <b> Location:Main Hall<br/>
    <b>Time:14:00<br/>
    <b>Day:Tuesday<br/>
    <b>Duration:1hour<br/>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p> 
    <b>Group:M</b>Code:98743<br/>
    <b> Session Type:NP<br/>
    <b> Location:Main Hall2<br/>
    <b>Time:11:00<br/>
    <b>Day:Monday<br/>
    <b>Duration:1hour<br/>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It does not work

Comment: @mplungjan yes, I checked it but its not working..