# How to validate data into paragraph's text using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to check if time and day is same when I click to add these paragraphs into the array, If time and day is same then also prevent adding items into an array. Can Anyone help me please.Thanks

```js
     window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var test = [];
      [...document.querySelectorAll(".container p")].forEach(function(para) {
        para.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          var text = e.currentTarget.textContent;
          if (test.indexOf(text) === -1) 
          {
          test.push(text); 
          }
          console.log(test)
        })
      })
    })
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <p>
          <b>Group:N</b>Code:1234<br/>
          <b>Session Type:</b>CS<br/>
          <b>Location:</b>Main Hall<br/>
          <b>Time:</b>11:00<br/>
          <b>Day:</b>Tuesday<br/>
          <b>Duration:</b>1hour<br/>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <p>
          <b>Group:M</b>Code:98743<br/>
          <b>Session Type:</b>NP<br/>
          <b>Location:</b>Main Hall2<br/>
          <b>Time:</b>11:00<br/>
          <b>Day:</b>Tuesday<br/>
          <b>Duration:</b>1hour<br/>
        </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: FYI: Converting the collection returned from `querySelectorAll()` into an Array is good practice for ensuring that older browsers that don't support `.forEach()` on node lists will be able to execute the `.forEach()`. However, those same browsers that don't support `.forEach()` on node lists also don't support the spread operator `...`, so that part of the statement will fail. The correct approach for backwards compatibility is `Array.prototype.slice.call(collection here).forEach(...)`.

Comment: As to your question, where/what gets clicked to initiate the array being populated? Right now, you are doing it automatically upon the window being loaded? Additionally, what is supposed to happen if the day/time are the same?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for your response. When I click on any "p" element then I need to check if time and day contain in paragraph must  be unique.I mean there is no other same day and time existing into an array..

Comment: @ScottMarcus if day and time are the same then display a error message.